# Sass in Laravel 5.4

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

In Laravel < 5.4 I was able to do the following with elixir to compile all of my sass files in one css file.

```
mix.sass([
    'file_1.scss',
    'file_2.scss',
    'file_n.scss'
], 'public/css/app.css');
```

In Laravel 5.4 this is not working. Is there a chance to do something similar in Laravel 5.4?

Comment: L5.4 removed elixir. The syntax is now different, you should [check the manual](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/mix#sass).

Comment: Already checked...can't find something there.

Comment: I can't imagine they removed it without replacing it with something new.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you've upgraded to Laravel Mix along with 5.4 then the syntax has changed. You should now use Sass the expected way. Create an `app.scss` file as the entry to your stylesheet, then use the `@import` tag to import other stylesheets.

```
@import 'file_1.scss';
@import 'file_2.scss';
@import 'file_n.scss';
```